# Alignment of three divs

Tags: css, html

I want the style of three div align as same as the following picture. How can I achieve that?

[image]

I write html code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
#container{
background-color:#00ff00;
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
#leftDiv{
background-color:#ff0000;
width:250px;
height:500px;
}
#rightDiv{
background-color:#0000fff;
widht:250px;
height:500px;
}
#other{
background-color:#ffff00;
widht:500x;
height:500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="leftDiv">
</div>
<div id="rightDiv">
<img src="Koala.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div id="other">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the result is not as my expectation，the is representation of my code：
[image]

I want to put a picture into the 2nd(rightDiv) div.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow can't display all my html code.I have no idea of how to make them appear.

Comment: There is no technical flaw in your code. It is just a typographic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi is very simple just change to your stylesheet and do it.

**css**

```
  .container{
background-color:green; width:500px;
}

.leftDiv{
background-color:red; width:250px;
height:500px;
float:left;
}

.rightDiv{
background-color:pink; width:250px;
height:500px;
float:left;
}

.other{
background-color: #FFFF00;
height:500px;
clear:both;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="leftDiv">left</div>
    <div class="rightDiv">right</div>

    <div class="other">middle</div>


</div>
```

and now check this  http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/PLdyw/4/

Comment: Using position absolute is not best approach for aligning divs. You should use float technique instead for better results.

Comment: @MuhammadSannanKhalid  You are right i have updated my answer .

Comment: @azad That's correct, I use your last version code,the result is not as  same as what i want,because in my div there are tables and other things. Use float, it works now. thanks everyone。

Answer (score 1):

The style rule you wrote for `#other` is wrongly typed. It should be `width` and not `widht`.

```
#other{
  background-color:#ffff00;
  widht:500x; /* This should have been 'width'. Resorting to StackOverflow for a typo error? :-o */
  height:500px;
}
```

PS: Please check your typographic errors before posting to StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,and sorry for typographic errors. But just correct spell error didn't work.

Comment: Then it might be because of the image width. It might be wider than 250px. If you change the `widht` to `width` it should work. I've already tested it(even though tiny things like these don't need any testing)

Answer (score 0):

try out this css.

```
.container{
background-color:green; width:500px;
height:500px;
position:relative;}

.leftDiv{
    float:left;
background-color:red; width:250px;
height:500px;
}

.rightDiv{
background-color:pink; width:250px;
height:500px;
float:left;
}

.other{
background-color: #FFFF00;
    clear:both;
    width:500px;
height:500px;
}
```